# Отслеживание экранной клавиатуры

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно отслеживать отображается экранная клавиатура или она скрыта.
Пробовал сделать по такому примеру:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Но у меня это не работает, пробовал и вариант с keyboardHidden. Хотя когда отслеживаю изменение ориентации экрана все работает нормально. 
В манифесте прописал `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard"`

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы спутали физическую клавиатуру с виртуальной. Вместо

> HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO и HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES

надо использовать

```
KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO /* или */ KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES
```

Comment: Попробовал с KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO и KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES, результат тот же, события не перехватываются.

Comment: А почему бы вам тогда не завести булеву переменную и назначать ей тру, когда клава появляется? Т.е. вы нажали на EditText и присвоили ей тру?

Comment: Тут вопрос как раз в том что бы отследить появление клавиатуры. По какому событию мне менять значение переменной?

Comment: Ну... Клава же у вас не просто так появляется? Надо в приложении на что-то нажать ведь, чтобы она появилась? Я вот, делая SearchView, именно по нажатию на него/скрытию/потере фокуса переменную менял

Comment: Ну в данном случае это EditText. Ну при тапе на него фокус появляется и открывается клавиатура. Но когда клавиатуру закрывает в поле по прежнему курсор стоит, то есть фокус еще там. Или я, что то не так понимаю? Как тогда можно снят фокус при закрытии клавиатуры?

Comment: Клава закрывается по нажатию назад или кнопки поиск или при потере фокуса. Фокус можно убрать назначив его любой другой вьюхе.

Comment: Все заработало как только повесил прослушку на метод onEditorAction. Спасибо за помощь!